# How does the private files folder need to be configured exactly?

Tags: 8, files

In `settings.php` I specified as `/home/username/myfiles`

Under Config > File System it shows the path, but when I add a file field to content, it does not show private upload as an option. I am wondering if it is because of how I specified the path? The path exists, and is writable. So I am confused.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ahhhh, just needed to clear cache...